# Translation of lost sinner

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Google comes with peccatorem perditum. Is this correct? I have had issues before where google has messed up the translation or word order. I mean it as a third person, a label, if we can say.

By lost I mean lost to god, lost in his ways. Example: I am lost without you.

It's going to be a tattoo implying that I am a lost sinner.

Comment: It's in the accusative case. If you want a general meaning, we can say "peccator perditus"

Comment: As Manuel implies, more context is needed. How will you use this? What do you mean by "lost sinner"? Lost as in you can't find them? Lost as in completely separated from god (but....you *can* see them*)? Lost as in *temporarily* separated? You need more information to get an appropriate translation, otherwise you might end up saying the wrong thing.

Comment: @cmw I have edited and clarified. Thanks

Comment: @lvdp Thanks for editing it. I'm still a bit confused, though. Lost to god? Lost can mean a couple different things, including lost = perished (gone forever) and lost = misplaced (hopefully soon will be found). Which definition are you going for here?

Comment: @cmw lost as in lost in ways, example: I am lost without you.

Comment: @lvdp Thanks for the context. Re-opened.

Comment: Thank you, @cmw